# Rustdoc bring module into scope?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I am writing a documentation for `crate` and I noticed I am having lot's references like this:

```
/// A struct [`MyStruct`][`modA::subB::subC::MyStruct`] is very beautiful.
```

Is there a way to bring module `subC` into scope within the doc comment? It would be wonderful if I could write something like:

```
/// #[use modA::subB::subC::MyStruct];
/// A struct [`MyStruct`] is very beautiful.
```

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's the best solution, but you can use a `#[cfg(doc)]` module that reexports the name:

```rust
pub mod super_long_a {
    pub mod super_long_b {
        pub mod super_long_c {
            pub struct Foo;
        }
    }
}

pub mod bar {
    #[cfg(doc)]
    mod doc_links {
        pub(super) use crate::super_long_a::super_long_b::super_long_c::Foo;
    }

    /// See [`Foo`](doc_links::Foo).
    pub fn qux() {}
}
```

Comment: What does it do exactly?

Comment: @SamuelHapak It creates a reexport and links to it, what is the question?

Comment: What is the point of ‘#[cfg(doc)]’?

Comment: @SamuelHapak It enables the module only for documentation, not for actual code.